# Error trying to add lines to txt

Tags: python

I can't make my code work.
I open the file with r+ attribute, print what's already in it, take 2 lines from the user, but cannot write these files:

```
file1 = open('test.txt', 'r+')
print "\n This is your file:\n"
print file1.read()
print "Now type in 2 lines:"
line1 = raw_input("Line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("Line 2: ")
print "Writing the lines"
file1.write(line1)
file1.write("\n")
file1.write(line2)
file1.write("\n")
print "\n This is your file again:\n"
print file1.read()
file1.close()
```

All I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Python27/new.py", line 10, in
>
> file1.write(line1)
>
> IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Comment: You opened `file1` for reading (`"r+"`). You cannot write into it. Asd a side note, `file1.read()` reads the whole file, to the end. The next time you call it, it reads nothing, because everything has been already read.

Comment: Use `w` or `wb`

Comment: From the doc: `r+ opens the file for both reading and writing.`

Comment: @mangoHero1 Both `w` and `wb` gives me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/new.py", line 4, in <module>
    print file1.read()
IOError: File not open for reading`

Comment: @mangoHero1 `w` creates a new file. From the doc: ´'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased)´

Comment: @Ed Morton I couldn't use any other tags besides the recommended ones. I had to use 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested code:

```
def func():
    with open('E:/test.txt', 'r') as f:
        print f.read()
    print "Now write 2 lines."
    l1 = raw_input("Line 1: ")
    l2 = raw_input("Line 2: ")
    with open('E:/test.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(l1 + "\n" + l2 + "\n")
    with open('E:/test.txt', 'r') as f:
        print ("This is your file now:\n" +
               f.read())
```

Output:

```
>>> func()
hey
therecoolguy
Now write 2 lines.
Line 1: cool
Line 2: guy
This is your file now:
hey
there
cool
guy
```

Assumes you have a `\n` at end of the file but that's the only condition.

Recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r/30931305#30931305) for more python file IO modes.

Comment: This worked. I'll study this and the link you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after you read and write the lines, you cannot do file1.read() again because you are starting that from the end of the file!

your last 3 lines should look like this:

```
    file1.seek(0) # go back to the start of the file
    print file1.read()
    file1.close()
```

but even more recommended is that you read and write on separate occasions, try this code:

```
    with open('file1.txt') as f:
        print f.read()
    print 'Now write 2 lines'
    line1 = raw_input('line1:')
    line2 = raw_input('line2:')
    print 'Writing lines'
    with open('file1.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(line1 + '\n' + line2 + '\n')
    with open('file1.txt') as f:
        print 'This is your file again:'
        print f.read()
```

Comment: Okay, but I can't write. The error is when I try to write the `line1`

Comment: Yes, I do believe the error within your code is your first `.read()` call. Try moving that to the end of your code and you should be fine.

Comment: If I add the ´.read()´ at the end, my txt file gets floodered with random data like:

´sb   d  Z  d d l m Z d d d „  ƒ  YZ e d k r^ d d l m Z e d d d  d
 e ƒn  d S(
   s9   Implement Idle Shell history mechanism with History classiÿÿÿÿ(   t   idleConft   Historyc           B   s;   e  Z d  Z d „  Z d „  Z d „  Z d „  Z d „  Z RS(   s@   Implement Idle Shell history mechanism.
    store - Store source statement (called from PyShell.resetoutput)..´

Comment: Your code gives me this 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/a.py", line 11, in <module>
    print f.read()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`